# Problem with MOSS tag

Tags: bug, status-completed, tagging

When I try to flag a question with MOSS, it tells me: sorry, the 'sharepoint-2007' tag is not allowed.  The 'sharepoint-2007' tag is new...
I realize that I can't create tags yet but it seems like the MOSS tag already exists.  Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are trying to avoid version specific tags. See [How do I use tags appropriately?](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264/how-do-i-use-tags-appropriately) for some guidelines or [What SharePoint SKUs are on-topic here and how should we tag them?](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82/what-sharepoint-skus-are-on-topic-here-and-how-should-we-tag-them).

In the meantime, you can put that your question applies to MOSS in the body of your question and tag your question with other tags. If it really is version specific, you can use [2007](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2007).

Comment: To avoid further confusion, I've removed both the tag synonym and the moss tag. If [moss] shows up again in the future, please ask for it to be blacklisted.