# Stack Exchange team: Shouldn't the 2010 tag be deleted again?

Tags: support, tagging

Brief recap:

1. Version tags were out of control
2. [Jeff deleted](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142/version-tags-considered-harmful) the [2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2010) tag
3. We now [only use tags that are version specific](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264/how-do-i-use-tags-appropriately/268#268)

...then all of the old SharePoint Overflow questions were migrated in and we're back to having over 1500 questions tagged with [2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2010).

Shouldn't this tag be deleted again so we can start from a clean slate and ensure that [2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2010) is only used when absolutely necessary?

Comment: Meanwhile don't ask me how we can be sure that almost 1400 questions tagged `2007` are version specific :( I know, I know, "just let it go Alex"!

Comment: I am updating the new questions almost exclusively right now. If I notice a high quality older question that needed updating, then we should probably try to update those as well.

Comment: Downvoter: Your contribution to this discussion would be appreciated A downvote on its own doesn't help much.

Comment: +1 from me. Not sure if I have an answer though.

Comment: @KitMenke Dang, I didn't make it clear that I'm asking the SE team! *Facepalm*

Comment: I've chatted to @RebeccaChernoff about this and she is looking at deleting this tag for posts imported from SP Overflow only.

Comment: (didn't follow the full story) what is the problem with the 2010 tag ? Isn't it the correct way to specify the version in the question ?

Comment: @SteveB The best summary I can give of why they're bad is [Jeff's post](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/153/numeric-version-tags-considered-ok). Does it make sense? Do you think we need to make it clearer on the "Ask Question" page?

Comment: @Alex Angas: I get a better picture now. My first reflex when posting is to specify the version I'm working on. I don't always know if the question may also relates to another version. So what is the correct approach ? Maybe not using the version tag, but in the question, specifying the version ?

Comment: @SteveB Yes, add it to the question text if you're not sure. Avoid using as a tag at all costs. :)

Answer (score 1):

Er.. what?

[Numeric version tags considered ... OK](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153/numeric-version-tags-considered-ok)

I thought we decided here that the [2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2010) tag was OK?

Comment: Indeed we do, provided as you said that it's "applied only to questions that are truly version specific". Our SE 1.0-era questions were not tagged with this guidance. Almost all of them are not specific to 2010 and will also apply to future versions yet to be released (exception: bugs - well hopefully). Right now the returned plethora of [tag:2010] is harming the site as casual users think every question should be tagged with a version, in some cases version tag only.

Comment: @alex was this handled, then? Should I do anything now?

Comment: No this hasn't been handled. Questions with [tag:2010] that have their most recent revision prior to April 7 2011 (our SE 2.0 migration date) should have this tag deleted.

Comment: @alex this is done; we elected not to touch questions with *only* the 2010 tag.

Comment: Cheers. Much appreciated.