# Site Cleanup Task Force for SharePoint Conference 2011

Tags: discussion, cleanup

[SharePoint Conference 2011](http://www.mssharepointconference.com/) is just around the corner and gives us a fantastic opportunity to promote the site! Getting out of beta in time for this would be a great boost to our community.

The only thing holding us back are [our Area 51 statistics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/28921/), the Stack Exchange guide to our site's health and quality. The main stat we've been asked to focus on is our answered rate.

So, what can you do to help? It's easy:

- **Upvote** helpful posts [from this list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes)
- **Edit** posts to improve formatting and findability according to [our list of tips](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115/have-any-tips-for-editing-questions/116#116)
- **Vote to close** questions that [don't belong here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/privileges/close-questions) (or flag them if you have < 500 rep)
- **Answer** questions that [have no answers](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers)

So, let's do it! Who's ready to make this site **a sensation at SPC 2011**??

Comment: Thanks to [Rich Ross](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/306/rich-ross) for the idea to rally around SPC2011.

Comment: I would suggest you go to *this* link for upvoting: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes

Comment: Alex, please make the StackExchange folks aware of the significance of the SPC11 target date.

Comment: And i suggest to use this list for removing/closing unanswered (sorted by newest, and last page) http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?page=17&tab=newest

Comment: For anyone else who wanted to [look it up](http://www.mssharepointconference.com/Pages/default.aspx), the dates are October 3 to October 6.

Comment: @AndersRask That link won't work once we no longer have page 17. I haven't found a way to hack the query string to work otherwise. Do you know how?

Comment: We probably need to get out of beta a few weeks ahead of SPC11 to give time get the site design and graphics sorted.

Answer (score 3):

I've been deleting questions that fit following criteria (or most of the following):

- 0 upvotes
- 0 answers
- Very low views (typically < 50)
- User abandoned the question (comment left for more information but never has been updated)
- User has not visited the site in months

Comment: Good job.......

Answer (score 2):

Great! I'm already on to it. I am currently using up my quota of votes every day.

There are currently 840 unanswered questions of which 398 have no answers. That means there are over 400 questions that have answers but not a single vote. I am finding that about 80% of these have at least one good, helpful answer. At 6000 questions we need to get down to below 600 unanswered questions which should be achievable.

Here's an example: OP posts comment against answer: "Thank you! Your suggestion worked perfectly". But doesn't accept or even up-vote. I'm seeing a lot like this.

Comment: Still note that @AlexAngas former related post/answer still holds true: "dont vote-up just to improve statistics", we want to maintain our reputation for top quality answers, since this counts for more than site statistics :-] http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/261/how-can-we-improve-our-answered-site-statistics/262#262

Comment: Agree. I am only upvoting answers that I consider *useful*. This is still a significant quality bar.

Comment: UPDATE 6 Aug 2011: Breakthrough! It seems to have tipped it over to 90%. Area 51 still says "Good" though (rounding error?). Let's keep going...